# Why is blender changing my bone matrices?

Tags: python, bones

I'm trying to build a skeleton and an animation, but the matrix I define when I create the bone changes.

importer.py:

```
...
new_bone.matrix = transform
print('Original matrix')
print(transform)
print('New Bone Matrix')
print(new_bone.matrix)
```

Console Output:

```
Original matrix
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.1515, -0.9884, -0.0100, -0.0000)
            (-0.9833,  0.1497,  0.1033, -1.9186)
            (-0.1006,  0.0254, -0.9946, 15.4413)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
New Bone Matrix
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.9969, 0.0000,  0.0000, -0.0000)
            ( 0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, -1.9186)
            ( 0.0000, 0.0000, -0.9969, 15.4413)
            ( 0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
```

Why blender do this?

Comment: Try copying the matrix instead of assigning it, new_bone.matrix = transform.copy()

Comment: Tried it, same results...